# File Loading in irb

Tags: ruby, file, file-io, irb

I have a Ruby method that should load a specified file when called:

```
 def self.from_file(file_name, origin = nil)
    MyFile.new(File.read(file_name), file_name.split('/').last, origin)
 end
```

But, when I try and use MyFile.from_file('path/to/file') in irb I get a "LoadError: no such file to load" message. Using Ruby 1.9.2p180 w/ RVM on Mac OS X.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So… does the file exist? Have you tried using an absolute rather than a relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file_name` you're loading needs to either be relative to your current path, or a full path.

If you're using a relative path, in irb you can check the output of `Dir.pwd` to see where `File.read` is trying to load your relative path from.